# Java - Enviar Email de Forma segura pela API do Gmail

Tags: java, email, envio-de-email, gmail

Estou utilizando uma `API` de e-mail `Mail.jar` deste [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_sending_email.htm) para envio de e-mail via `Java`, porém percebi que tenho que, ativar a permissão para aplicativos menos seguros.
Existe outra forma de enviar e-mail `Java`, sem que precise ativar essa opção do Gmail de aplicativos menos seguros?

[image: Print da seção de Aplicativos menos seguros]

Comment: Tente realizar a configuração de conexão SMTP com SSL ativo. Você pode tentar com o tutorial deste link: [https://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/](https://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/)

Comment: Existe, tem que usar o fluxo XOAUTH2 do Google. Sua aplicação direciona o usuário para o Google, ele loga no Google, autoriza seu app, e o Google redireciona de volta com um token. Com esse token, enquanto o usuário não desautorizar, seu aplicativo obtem as credenciais de login sempre que precisar acessar o SMTP.

Comment: @CarlosSilva o código mostrado no exemplo é o que eu uso, ai tem que ativar a autorização para aplicativos menos seguros

Comment: @Bacco estou pesquisando sobre o XOAUTH2 e java

Comment: @Carlos não tenho como ajudar com a parte do Java especificamente por falta de experiência com a linguagem, mas o fluxo é basicamente o seguinte: sua aplicação direcionará o usuário para o Google para obter um token de aplicação no primeiro acesso, e em seguida, sempre que for usar o SMTP, usará este token de aplicação para obter um token de sessão. Este token de sessão é usado no lugar da senha do SMTP, sempre que você precisar. Quando expirar o token de sessão, o token de aplicação te permite solicitar um novo. O de aplicação não expira nunca, enquanto o usuário não revogar acesso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem 3 hipóteses para enviar um email através do Gmail:

- Ativar essa tal opção para aplicações menos seguras, embora esta não possa ser utilizada se a conta tiver o TFA ativo.
- Usar [palavra-passe de aplicação](https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords), embora o utilizador tenha de criar uma para enviar o email.
- Usar a [API do Google](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending) para Java que abre uma página na web onde se pode dar login na conta, mesmo esta tendo TFA **(recomendada)**.

É importante saber que o exemplo da Google vem com premissões para ver as etiquetas. Para alterar isso, basta ir à lista `SCOPES` e alterar `GmailScopes.GMAIL_LABELS` para `GmailScopes.GMAIL_COMPOSE`.